# Fullbody Detection Using OpenCV Haar Cascades

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I want to detect the full body of human within image using OpenCV fullbody Haar Cascades. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

bodydetection = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
img = cv2.imread('gambar/fullbody2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
body = bodydetection.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in body:
   cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here's the result:

[image: Result]

As you can see, my code didn't detect the full body of human in the image.

By the way I'm newbie in OpenCv and this is my first question in here, so just correct me if I'm doing something wrong and I hope someone can help me to correct my code.

Sorry for bad English ;).

Comment: i suggest you to try [peopledetect.py](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/peopledetect.py) AFAIK `cv2.HOGDescriptor()` is better than `cv2.CascadeClassifier` on fullbody detection

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the OpenCV `haarcascade_fullbody.xml`, which contains the data to detect whether it is a human or not,

Please try to add a photo with a group of people (not only one person) and see if it detects any of them.

Answer (score 0):

cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_fullbody.xml')

use this

Comment: Why? What is the effect? How does that help to solve the problem?

Comment: Avoiding additional file downloads, it is preferable to utilize OpenCV for the task at hand. However, it is essential to acknowledge certain limitations in full-body detection. The model occasionally exhibits suboptimal performance in specific images, struggling to achieve accurate detections. Please take note of these considerations as we address the identified challenges.

Comment: Please [edit] towards [answer] by adding the explanation to the answer post itself. And you might enjoy this info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting